# How to view registered devices for Azure Notifications Hub on a Mac?

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am working on an iOS app and signed up for Azure notifications hub to use their push notifications service.

However I immediately ran into a problem as I set up everything but push is not going through. I looked up a solution to debug this situation and the documentation seems to lead me to downloading "Service Bus Explorer" https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a However this requires I have visual studio running, which requires that I have Windows. It's ridiculous if this is the case, since obviously you need to be on a Mac to develop an iOS app.

Am I missing something or is this for real? Anyone have advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet may be to install Node.js locally on your Mac and [use the azure NPM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-nodejs-how-to-use-notification-hubs/) to query the Notification Hub. Create a script:

```
var azure = require('azure-sb');
var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService('hubname','connectionstring');
notificationHubService.listRegistrations(function(err, registrations) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(registrations));
});
```

and then you can run

```
node scriptname.js
```

You may want to iterate through the registrations, pretty-print the parts that are useful to you, and so on.

Unfortunately, the documentation is scarce or well-hidden, so it is good to keep the [NPM source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/serviceBus/lib/notificationhubservice.js) bookmarked to see what the functions are.

Having Windows in a virtual machine to query the Notification Hub with Visual Studio is also an alternative. I don't find myself using it to work with Notification Hubs, though, just for optimizing queries in SSMS.

Comment: for me works with require('azure-sb') instead of require('azure')